# How do it set up automatic DataFrame structure when I scan the data in Excel to python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, dataframe, machine-learning

My data in Excel is not separated by ",". Twitter data separated by columns. When I throw it in Python, it automatically installs DataFrame and Tweets are not showed full text. How can I overcome this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAXSq.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a copy open in Excel, the easiest solution would be to save a copy as a csv.
File -> Save As -> dropdown and select CSV.
But pandas also allows you to read excel files. This would be recommended if you have a lot of files and don't want to convert all of them.

```
df = pd.read_excel(<file>)
```

Now, if you're saying it isn't .xlsx and also not .csv, but *you know the delimiter*, then:

```
df = pd.read_csv(<file>, delimiter='\t')  # for tab delimited, but you can change '\t' to any delimiter
```

Comment: I have too many files. File type CSV. But the data is separated by columns. I want it seperated with ",". And can I add multiple CSV files?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean that "the data is separated by columns". All files will appear to be delimited this way when opened in Excel, but I don't think "column" is an actual delimiter. **Open the file in notepad or notepad++ and find what character is used between data entries**. Excel does this automatically, but for pandas, you would have to know the delimiter.